# How can one search for matrimonial cases in the New Jersey court system?

Tags: divorce, new-jersey, court-records, public-records

Can anyone help me in my quest for finding updated listings of matrimonial cases in New Jersey?

I have looked at the ["Find a Case" page of the New Jersey Courts](https://www.njcourts.gov/public/find-a-case) website but I cannot find any feature that allows me to see all cases of a particular type. For example, I want to see all matrimonial cases filed today.

I know this is possible in other states, [like New York for example](https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/nyscef/CaseSearch), but I cannot see how to do it with New Jersey or if it's at all possible

Comment: What is your purpose for searching? If you are trying to find out if a particular person is getting a divorce a simple name search ought to suffice. If you are trying to get a list of all people who are divorcing for example for marketing purposes, that is another thing.

Comment: I'm trying to collect data to research trends among neighboring states

Comment: @Ighost In that case, the court administrator of the state court system probably publishes docket information in an annual statistical report, and you can probably do a freedom of information act request (or the NJ equivalent) to get greater detail.